# Calling delete on C API to C++ interface segfaults with debug build

Tags: c++, c, memory, delete-operator

I'm having an issue where I have some code that wraps a C++ class, like the following:

C++:

```
class A
{
  A() {}
  ~A() {}
}
```

C Interface:

```
typedef struct c_a c_a;
void c_a_new(c_a * self)
{
  self = reinterpret_cast<c_a *>(new A());
}
void c_a_delete(c_a * self)
{
  delete reinterpret_cast<A*>(self);
}
```

C Code:

```
c_a * self;
c_a_new(self);
c_a_delete(self);
```

I am building with gcc using CMake as a build system. Everything is fine when `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is set to `Release` or `RelWithDebInfo`, but I get a segfault on calling `c_a_delete(self);` when it is set to `Debug`. This seems to occur on all of my classes with the C interface. If I comment out the `delete` call in `c_a_delete()`, it seems to fix that case. I imagine this may result in a memory leak though. Is there any chance the compiler might be optimizing the memory usage in the release builds or is something else going on?

Comment: c_new should return a pointer. (do not pass a reference or pointer to pointer). c_delete is fine.

Comment: For the Love of God, **do** use static code analyzers (e.g. Visual Studio's).

Comment: What does `void f(int i) {i = 5;}` and `int x = 7; f(x); cout << x << endl;` print?

Comment: @DieterLücking would returning from `c_new` be preferred in this case from returning an `int` with status code and taking a pointer as a parameter?

Comment: @immibis That would print 7. But in my case, I'm taking a `c_a*` as a parameter, which would kind of be like taking an `int*` as a parameter in your example, in which case `f(&x); cout << x << endl;` would print 5. I suppose what I'm wondering is what about this being a struct causes the pointer to behave differently? Is a struct `a` passed by value when `*a` is a parameter to a function, in which case it would need to be referenced (but appear as **a) to pass it by reference?

Comment: @danielu13: You are still passing the pointer **by value**. No different from passing an `int` by value.

Comment: @danielu13 There is a difference between `int x; f(&x);` and `int *x; f(x);`. In the first case, `f` can modify whatever the pointer points to, which is `x`. In the second case, `f` can modify whatever the pointer points to, which is **not `x`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want modification to an `int` to be visible outside of a function, one way is to pass a pointer to the the int, for example:

```
void foo(int * i) {
  *i = 42;
}
```

so that the following holds:

```
int i = 1;
foo(&i);
assert(i == 42);
```

Similarly, if you want modification to `c_a *` to be visible outside of a function, one way is to pass a pointer to it, for example:

```
void c_a_new(c_a ** pself)
{
  *pself = new A;
}
```

and call it as

```
c_a * self = NULL;
c_a_new(&self);
```

---

IMHO, design wise it is better to return the pointer instead of passing it by pointer and updating, i.e. something like

```
c_a * c_a_new()
{
  return new (std::nothrow) A;
}
```

Comment: And since that is meant to be consumed by C code it should really be `return new(std::nothrow) A;`.

Comment: If I do the way that returns a new object, should I use returns in other functions as well? To my knowledge, most of error handling in C is done by returning a status code. When creating a new object, I can just check that the object exists by something like `if(!c_a_new())`, but this wouldn't be the case if there was a function `float A::f()`. Would it be better to do a C function of `float c_a_f()` or `int c_a_f(float * out)` where the int returned is some status? In the first case, how would errors be handled?

Comment: In this case, the return value conveys the success vs. failure -- any non-NULL return value is success and NULL return value is failure. So, for this case, I think this is appropriate. I always try this approach first. But in cases where the return value may not be indicative of success vs. failure, then returning a status code is okay in C code.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing pointer by value and you're not updating the original. Use return values or pointers to pointers. (I also added an additional handle typedef to make this more in sync with other C apis)

```
typedef struct c_a c_a, *a_handle;
void c_a_new(a_handle* self)
{
    *self = reinterpret_cast<a_handle>(new A());
}
void c_a_delete(a_handle self)
{
    delete reinterpret_cast<A*>(self);
}
```

and then call

```
a_handle self;
c_a_new(&self);
c_a_delete(self);
```

Or just return the acquired pointer:

```
typedef struct c_a c_a, *a_handle;
a_handle c_a_new(a_handle* self)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<a_handle>(new A());
}
void c_a_delete(a_handle self)
{
    delete reinterpret_cast<A*>(self);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
a_handle self = c_a_new();
c_a_delete(self);
```